# The background for the div does not fit from the left side and make an unwanted scroll

Tags: css

Hi guys I explain my problem in this image.
[image]

I use this code to make a background to the div

```
.intro .bg-img{
     position: absolute;
     background: green url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/7350/startup-photos.jpg');
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: center;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     width:100%;
     height:350px;
     z-index: -1;
     opacity: 0.5;
}
```

here is the all code
https://codepen.io/haithamsha/pen/LeVZVr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code you have CSS that applies a 1em padding to every div within the wrapper class.

To fix this you can apply `padding: 0 !important;` to your intro class.

```
.intro {
    grid-column: span 1;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 350px;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 !important; /* Apply important here */
    margin: 0;
}
```

Or you need to remove the `1em` padding from every div and be more granular with your padding.

```
.wrapper > div {
   /* background: #ddd; */
   padding: 1em; /*<-- Remove this*/
}
```

Hope that helps